# delegate method does not get called

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I'm completely stuck with calling a method from a UIView subclass, the method just doesn't get fired, I have a feeling that I'm doing something wrong but after searching the web I did not find any clue. Thank you in advance

Here's the iPadMainViewController.h file

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "TouchView.h"

@interface iPadMainViewController : UIViewController <TouchViewDelegate> 

@property (retain) UIWebView *detailsView;

@end
```

and the iPadMainViewController.h file that holds the method

```
- (void)MethodNameToCallBack:(NSString *)s
{
    NSLog(@"%@",s);
}
```

Here's the TouchView.h file, which is supposed t

```
@protocol TouchViewDelegate
- (void)MethodNameToCallBack:(NSString *)s;
@end

@interface TouchView : UIView {
    id<TouchViewDelegate> delegate;
}

@property (nonatomic, assign) id delegate;

@end
```

Here's the TouchView.m file which is supposed to call a method of it's delegate

```
@implementation TouchView
@synthesize delegate;


-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    NSLog(@"HELLO FROM INSIDE");

    [[self delegate] MethodNameToCallBack:(NSString *)@"HELLO FROM OUTSIDE"];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Synthesizing the delegate is not enough, because it just creates the getter and the setter methods. It does not create an instance of `iPadMainViewController`.

So after you create an instance of `TouchView`, you should assign an instance of `iPadMainViewController` as the delegate.

```
iPadMainViewController *controller = [[iPadMainViewController alloc] init...
// ...
TouchView *touchView = [[TouchView alloc] init...
// ...
touchView.delegate = controller;
```

Or in the iPadMainViewController's viewDidLoad method:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    // ...
    self.touchView.delegate = self;
}
```

Comment: I wonder why none of the examples i found mentioned that, many many thanks!

Comment: Why would you create a new iPadMainViewController, surely TouchView is a view contained within the existing iPadMainViewController's view?

Answer (score 0):

check after you instantiated a TouchView instance, did you assign its delegate?

Answer (score 0):

Enhance your touchesBegan implementation a little for further debugging:

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    NSLog(@"HELLO FROM INSIDE");
    NSLog(@"our delegate is set towards: %@", delegate);
    ...
}
```

Does it log something useful in that second logging statement?

I presume it prints `nil` and that would be the root cause of your issue; you forgot to assign the delegate.